# datagridview cell edit error

Tags: datagridview, editor, cell

On a Windows form I have an unbound datagridview with 1 user-editable column. A user clicked into one of those cells, changed his mind and closed the form using the "x". Then he tried to bring up the form again. The following error came up:

"System.InvalidOperationException: Operation did not succeed because the program cannot commit or quit a cell value change"

The error actually occurs where I do a datagridview.rows.clear before displaying the form via a show.dialog.

I added a DataGridView.CancelEdit() to the FormClosing event but the error remains.

I tried to comment out the rows.clear code but then each row appeared twice.  The data source of the datagridview is a collection.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the instance of the form = Nothing and the problem disappeared